# How do I generate a random number every second and get the average?

Tags: objective-c

I am having trouble trying to get a **random number** every second and **log it** as well as it's running average.

**Code:**

```
-(void)generateNumber:(NSTimer *)numberEachSecond
{        
    NSUInteger random = (arc4random() % 1000) +1;        
    NSMutableArray *listOfNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];        
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:random];        
    [listOfNumbers addObject:number];        

    // NSNumber *counter = 0;        
    for (NSNumber *generatedNumber in listOfNumbers) 
    {  
        NSLog(@"%@",generatedNumber);            
    }        
    NSLog(@"%@", listOfNumbers);        
}
```

Comment: I'm just having trouble dealing with trying to perform math on the numbers that are generated such as obtaining an average. I want to be able to continuous add the random numbers together and divide by the count of numbers, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for generating random number seems good but you should not alloc array each time into that function `generateNumber`, it should be something like,

alloc array somewhere that for once or when needed, may be in `viewDidLoad` ?

```
listOfNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //listOfNumbers should be instance variable

-(void)generateNumber:(NSTimer *)numberEachSecond 
{
    NSUInteger random = (arc4random() % 1000) +1;
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:random];
    [listOfNumbers addObject:number];
}
```

You can use it anywhere outside the function,

```
NSLog(@"%@", listOfNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will generate a random number every second, and calculate the average of all the numbers
generated.

in the .h

```
NSMutableArray *listOfNumbers;
```

int the .m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    listOfNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(generateNumber:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)generateNumber:(NSTimer *)numberEachSecond
{
NSUInteger random = (arc4random() % 1000) +1;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:random];
[listOfNumbers addObject:number];
int total=0;
NSLog(@"%@",generatedNumber);  
for (NSNumber *generatedNumber in listOfNumbers)
{
    total=total + [generatedNumber intValue];
}

int average= total/[listOfNumbers count];
NSLog(@"average -- %d", average);
}
```